# IsolateStorage Issue in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I am facing the problem regarding the following issue in wp7

**"Type 'System.Windows.Media.Transform' cannot be serialized in C#"**

When i call the below method to save my List data to isolated storage

SerializeHelper.SaveSetting("myfile.Xml",swaplist);

then then i am getting the exception.

```
public static class SerializeHelper
    {
        public static void SaveSetting<T>(string fileName, T dataToSave)
        {
            using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var stream = store.CreateFile(fileName))
                    {
                        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                        serializer.WriteObject(stream, dataToSave);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I am attaching the screenshot of structure of list data[image]

How to resolve this?

Comment: This error means, that you are trying to serialize some unserializable object. SolidColorBrush, maybe? You can resolver this by serializing not whole object, but only properties that you want to, on by writing your own serializer. Maybe you should show code givig this error.

Comment: I am not serializing any SolidColorBrush Object?

Comment: So, show us your code, so we can know what are you serializing :)

Comment: I have added the screen shot which is showing the process of saving the data in to isolated storage.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for adding the screenshot... and pasting some code. Can't really see anything wrong.

does you VM only expose public primitive / serialisable types ? I have in past used something like this to serialise to iso store.

```
public static void SaveObjectToStorage<T>(T ObjectToSave)
{
    TextWriter writer;

    using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = isf.OpenFile(GetFileName<T>(), System.IO.FileMode.Create))
        {
            writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            ser.Serialize(writer, ObjectToSave);
            writer.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: the screenshot or the code weren't there.. don't down vote it you didn't see the question prior to additional info being submitted

Comment: Are all properties of the view model exposing primitive types only? can't really see anything wrong with the code.. I have in past used XmlSerializer for this

Comment: no, not all properties of primitive types, most of them are derived type

Comment: @MuditBajpai so, you are sure that all this derived type are serializable?

Comment: also set the serializable attribute on classes